# ToolingAPI.cls for Apex: How to get CompilerErrors at ContainerAsyncRequest in v31+?

Tags: apex, error-messages, tooling-api

Im trying to patch [ToolingAPI.cls](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) in order to use it with API v32. I run it successfully for a couple of month now with v29/30, but due to changes to the API, I need to adapt some parts. Unfortunately the latest version available on github is for v30.

So far I got somthing which works partly, **but**:

looking at the tooling.wsdl for v32 at `<xsd:complexType name="ContainerAsyncRequest">` it has lost the element `<xsd:element name="CompilerErrors" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>` which I've used to obtain the error details, e. g. when I save an ApexClass containing syntax error, this was the element I used to get the error.

Now, since it's gone, how an where can I get the compiler error message? It's not in `<xsd:element name="ErrorMsg" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>` - this one stays empty on syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been replaced by DeployDetails

```
<xsd:element name="DeployDetails" minOccurs="0" type="tns:DeployDetails" nillable="true"/>
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_deploydetails.htm

> A complex type that contains detailed XML for any compile errors
>   reported in the asynchronous request defined by a
>   ContainerAsyncRequest object. Replaces the JSON field CompilerErrors
>   in Tooling API version 31.0 and later.

**UPDATE**

First I still wasn't able to retrieve this information, because I got an `Illegal value for primitive` error. I've asked another question in order to show my problem and finally is solved thanks to the help of @DanielBallinger here:

[Patching ToolingAPI.cls for v31+: How to query for DeployDetails at ContainerAsyncRequest?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57534/patching-toolingapi-cls-for-v31-how-to-query-for-deploydetails-at-containerasy)